# jQuery - Take control of the page when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, viewport

I got this website in which there are 5 blocks and everyone has got the viewport size, 100% width and 100% height. So when the page loads you can just see the 1st one. The other ones are beneath it. Then when you scroll down you see the 2nd one, then the 3rd one and so on, until you reach the end of the page where the last one is located. I was thinking if there's a way to force the page scrolling block-by-block instead of the default linear way. I'd like the user to see directly (well, not directly, but with an animation, if possible) the 2nd block when he scrolls down instead of seeing the way in between the two blocks. Those blocks are like different pages and, without clicking anywhere (cause that would be the easiest (and atm the only) way for me to make it working), I'd like to move across them page-by-page, just scrolling. Is that possible? Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried using the scrollTo plugin, but I couldn't figure it out either.
Let's just take in account when user scrolls down to make it easier.
This is what I did:

```
var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0; // 2 vars to check if user scrolls down
var isScrolling = false;
var nextPage = 2 // I'm on 1st page, I want to show page 2 when user scrolls down;
$(window).scroll(function(){
  currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // current position

  if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop && ! isScrolling ){ // if user scrolls down
    isScrolling = true; // animation in progress, shouldn't get into this 'if' till finished
    $(window).scrollTo('section#page-' + nextPage, 1000, {
        onAfter: function(){ isScrolling = false; nextPage++; }
    });
  }

  tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop; // update the current position
});
```

The 'if' statement checks if user scrolled down.
Technically it should work, BUT after showing me the page I want, he just goes to the next one, then the one after, and it keeps scrolling down till the end! Doing a bit of testing, I've seen that the code that should be executed after EVERY SINGLE animation (which means a single whole-page-scroll) gets executed randomly. I mean, isScrolling = false doesn't occurr, while nextPage++ does, that's why it keeps scrolling (cause it goes to the next page, in fact). Shouldn't it do this AFTER the animation is done, instead of while it's going? I'm confused..

Comment: Kind of like the way Acrobat Reader works when you set it to non-continuous mode?

Comment: Hide the blocks by default except for the first one. When the user scrolls past the height of the block, show the next block. You can animate it in if you want. Not sure if that is what you're talking about...

Comment: @Barmar kind of, but a bit different cause I still want the animation when scrolling, but with stops when you reach pages.

Comment: @donutdan4114 that sounds like an interesting idea! thank you, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to do that is [jQuery.ScrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com.es/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

It's very easy to setup, and allows for all kind of animations and ways of expressing where you want to scroll.

And you need to handle the scroll events, [using this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/)

With a combination of both you get what you want.

To scroll to the next or previous element you should keep track of the current visible item to be able to go to the next or previous one.

You also need to keep track of scroll position (sccrollTop property) whenever you use scrollTo, so that you can guess if the user is scrolling up or down.

Finally, you probably need a "scrolling flag" set when the user starts scrolling, and unset when he stops scrolling, so that you know if you have to keep looking at the scroll position after each scrollTo movement.

Another option is to use jQuery tools, but you should change the desing to something like [this demo](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.html). This isn't what you asked for, but I think it offers a better UX.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. Probably in this way I'll get what I'm looking for. I already know scrollTo as I used it in a few project, never heard of the other plugin tho. But in which way should I combine them? How could a possible solution be? Thanks!

Comment: You've got to write a little bit of code to keep track of the current visible panel, and the current scroll position. Then, when the user starts scrolling up or donw (start event, check for new position), use scroll to to go to the next or previous panel. You can keep scrolling panel after panel until he stops scrolling (the other event). You can also adjust the final position after the stop scrolling event to get sure the scroll is where it should be even if something else fails. See edition.

Comment: I appreciate your help JotaBe, I thought I got what you meant and theoretically I do, but I can't get it done in code. Any ideas how to code it? The special scroll plugin uses a timer so it's not extremely reliable (I guess) and scrollTo is just not enough.. Dunno..

Comment: I updated my question adding a bit of code to explain what I've done and maybe let you get what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause is, when the first animation stops and isScrolling is unset, a scroll event is triggered anyway, so you get another animation till the page reaches to bottom. I ever got such issue when I tried to unset the scrolling flag when animation stopped. A simple solution is to delay unsetting the scrolling flag, e.g.

```
$(window).scrollTo('section#page-' + nextPage, 1000, {
    onAfter: function() {
        setTimeout(function() { isScrolling = false; nextPage++; }, 100);
    }
});
```